# Is my Github completely broken? Or am I using it wrong

Tags: git, github, repository, push, clone

When ever I have used github recently I have encountered a series of bug-like problems.

**Context**: I have been using git for about a year without running into these problems in till now. Whenever I tried to push to a repository I would get errors saying that I do not have the permissions: even if it was public or I had specifically accepted the invitation to edit from the host.

It even says that when trying to push to my own branch. Now more recently when I try to clone a repository (a public one) I get the error:

> (base) Andrews-MacBook-Pro-2:~ andrew-----$ git clone https://github.com/----/------
>   Cloning into '------'...
>   remote: Repository not found.
>   fatal: repository 'https://github.com/-----/----/' not found

I have tried completely reinstalling git but this has not solved the issue. I am on macOS, of the most recent update and will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Github and was because i activated the two-factor authentication after i disable it i didn't run into any more issues.

Comment: You don't need to disable 2FA because of that. You should use access tokens with the command line git instead.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case as I do not have that enabled, thanks for the suggestion though.